# How to align toggle button with image button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-togglebutton

I am using a toggle button for selecting favorites and I've got several other image buttons in the same row. However, because toggle button doesn't behave similar to image button, my icons aren't aligning properly.

Also, I'm setting the image for the toggle button programmatically, because it needs to have a changed button based on what the user selected. I do that programatically like this:

```
  if (holder.favButton.isChecked())
     holder.favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().
          getDrawable(R.drawable.star_fill));
  else
     holder.favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().
          getDrawable(R.drawable.star_empty));
```

Please see the screenshot. Both the icons in this image are 24 x 24

[image]

This is my layout:

I've tried several combinations but none seem to work

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_c1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/fav_rec"
        android:layout_width="35px"
        android:layout_height="35px"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15px"
        android:textOn="" android:textOff="" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="35px"
        android:layout_height="35px"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:src="@drawable/pencil_1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `paddingBottom` and `layout_alignParentLeft` on both the `ToggleButton` and `ImageButton`.

Then add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to your parenting `LinearLayout`, and `android:gravity="center"` to your `ToggleButton` and `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/share_c1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/fav_rec"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

Note : try use dp or dip insted of px in layout.
```